# Executing Get-AzContainerGroup in powershell returns empty table

Tags: azure, powershell

Following some basic tutorials I have created azure container instance via azure portal web. Now I want to be able to get this container instance using windows powershell.

When I connect to my azure account via windows powershell and run following command

```
Get-AzContainerGroup
```

I get the this result

[image]

Which is basically empty table moreover different from the one I'd expected (follows example output from Get-AzContainerGroup microsoft documentation page)

[image]

When I tried to debug the command, I got no errors and moreover in the response body I can actually see all information about that particular container instance, but the result table shows nothing and has different columns than the example output.

The container instance was created using one of the prepared microsoft quick images

```
mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld:latest
```

and is set to be on private network (could this be reason?)

For that particular resource group the container was created in I have the contributor rights.

Am I missing some other important point to get this empty table result instead of correct table listing my one running container instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try out below commands:

Get-AzContainerGroup -Name  -ResourceGroupName | Format-List
(or)

Get-AzContainerGroup | Format-List
(or)

Get-AzContainerGroup -Name  -ResourceGroupName  | select-object Name , OSType , SKU

Example Output:

[image]

Comment: I tried and...... it worked. So basically when I run command 'Get-AzContainerGroup' without any parameters and without Format-List or select-object utilities it returns table with all the properties (columns) and since the ones which fit into screen were empty it looked like empty table is returned. Gosh. Don't understand  why the documentation of the 'Get-AzContainerGroup' command does not mention select-object utility and leads to wrong impression only few columns are returned. Anyway thank you.